# Russian to English transliteration in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

What are the native tools for string transliteration from Russian to English in Simfony2?

**UPD** i need transliteration, not translation, example

```
б => b, ю => yu
привет => privet
```

I need to convert any string of Russian language in the English alphabet

Comment: @DonCallisto Translation != Transliteration

Comment: @Xatoo: you're right! Didn't noticed the exact word :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native tools for Symfony, but there is "native" PHP tools in Intl library.

For example

```
$transliterator = \Transliterator::create('Any-Latin');
$transliteratorToASCII = \Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII');
$transliterateTitle = $transliteratorToASCII->transliterate($transliterator->transliterate($title));
```

In first place we transliterate Russian to Latin, then we transliterate it to ASCII.

If you don't like this method, you just can take something like in this example http://htmlweb.ru/php/example/translit.php. Just create class with such method end register it as service.

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 5  was introduced new component **String**
You can transliterate and convert, splice, change case and other

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/string.html#methods-added-by-codepointstring-and-unicodestring

Answer (score -3):

Please consider looking at the symfony translation documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html